# Non-isomorphic abelian groups of order 360

Tags: group-theory

How to calculate the number of non-isomorphic abelian groups of order 360 and number of elements of order 60 there?

I tried to base on Sylow theorem but I didn't get any serious advances as a result.

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem on finite abelian groups. The classification of these groups is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $360 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1$. Then, because of the primary decomposition, the number of non-isomorphic abelian groups of order $360$ is $p(3)\cdot p(2) \cdot p(1)$, where $p(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$.

Let $G = G_2 \times G_3 \times G_5$ be the primary decomposition of an abelian group of order $360$.

Let $N(n,G)$ be the number of elements of order $n$ in $G$.

Then $N(60,G) = N(4,G_2) \cdot N(3,G_3) \cdot N(5,G_5)$.

Comment: Great! What about number of elements of order 60?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? How isomorphic+abelian restriction leads to number of partitions, possibly with some simple example of group of smaller order say 4 or 6? I must be missing something very basic which might get cleared once I have look at an example.